# mysql db normalization help required

Tags: php, mysql, database

please forgive me as Ive been confused and I need your help in normalization of this next mysql database (will work on it along with php). If this is not allowed to post it then ignore :)

- I've a need to record large number students to visit a library in order to document it and create analysis and reports later on.
- These visits will hold lots of data and criteria for each student single visit, and it will be filled by different supervisor people because the student will visit more than one section.
- Hence, there will be some limitations for entry and disallowing certain parts of the form to be accessed by certain users...etc.
- My plan is to have a single form with some initial student information and select boxes, radio, checkboxes, and notes as free text, for each visit, as i mentioned, using php as frontend

This is what i have in mind, 2 main tables + other smaller tables to hold the select boxes data as foreign keys.

**TABLE1: STUDENTS**

1. student_id
2. student_number
3. student_name
4. student_gender
5. student_grade
6. student dateofbirth
7. student age

**TABLE2: VISITS**

1. studnet_id (referring and pulling student info from TABLE1)
2. date_of_visit
3. have_did_this_during_the_visit (DropDown)
4. psychological_reaction (checkboxes)
   5 was_wearing_well (yes not selectbox)

**And so on, more than 50 criteria to measure for each visit**

This way, will have finally 2 forms, one to add student, and one to deal with visits...

Although, visits form/page will be big.. and here comes my question, is this ok? these data of visits table can exceed 40 or 50 fields or do you guys advise different approach?

Thanks for your help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have_did_this_during_the_visit (DropDown).

for this you need one table this table will have pk anf fk on visits table's primary key

psychological_reaction (checkboxes) 5 was_wearing_well (yes not selectbox)

for this you need one table this table will have pk anf fk on visits table's primary key

**TABLE2: VISITS**

```
    visit_id
    studnet_id (referring and pulling student info from TABLE1)
    date_of_visit
    have_did_this_during_the_visit (DropDown)
    psychological_reaction (checkboxes) 5 was_wearing_well (yes not selectbox)
```

**have_did_this_during_the_visit**

```
id
visit_id
you DropDown vaues
```

**psychological_reaction**

```
id
visit_id
you checkboxes vaues
```

Comment: yes vaibhav, this is what i am thinking of, all those small checks/selects will get the data from different small tables as pk fk... my question is this ok? to put all 50 fields in one table as "visits" then pull the data from as fk from smaller tables?

Comment: yes. This is the way when our database is well designed.

Comment: This is the standard way of designing the database.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks for confirming and for your time in reading my story :) appreciated.